# Better approach to test the function

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, refactoring

I try to write the unit test for this simple function. Basically, it receives a payload from Slack then builds a message and then send this message to the user using API.

```
@slack_messages.on_pattern('(?i)^help$')
def handle_help_message(event, body, match):
    message = build_help_message()
    Slack(event['team_id']).send_message(body['user'], **message)

def build_help_message():
    text = "Hello"

    return {
        'text': text,
        'attachments': [
            build_basics(),
            build_controls()
        ]
    }
```

I wrote this test, but it looks too complex for such a simple function. How can I make my test simpler?

```
class TestMesssageHandlers(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('slango.slack.Slack.send_message')
    @mock.patch('slango.slack.Slack.__init__')
    @mock.patch('apps.slackapp.help.handlers.build_help_message')
    def test_handle_help_message(self, build_message_mock, init_mock,
                                 send_message_mock):
        init_mock.return_value = None
        build_message_mock.return_value = {
            'text': mock.sentinel.text,
            'attachments': mock.sentinel.attachments
        }

        event = {
            'team_id': 'TEAMID',
            'event': {
                'text': 'help',
                'user': 'U111111'
            }
        }

        handle_help_message(event, event['event'])

        init_mock.assert_called_with(event['team_id'])
        send_message_mock.assert_called_with(
            event['event']['user'], **build_message_mock.return_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit-testing is for findings those bugs that can be detected in the isolated code.  Your example code, however, is dominated by interactions with the `Slack` component.  That is, if there are bugs in this piece of code, they will be related to how you call the `Slack` constructor and the `send_message` method.

You will, however, not find these bugs with mocks of the Slack class: Imagine the correct named arguments to the `send_message` method are not `text` and `attachments`, but `txt` and `attach` - with your mocks, you will never notice this problem, because your mocks reflect your (mis-)understanding of how the other components work.

The conclusion is, that for this kind of code unit-testing is not the right approach, but integration testing is.  If you need more examples, you could also take a look at these questions, which go in a similar direction: [Mock a series of interdependent calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016901/mock-a-series-of-interdependent-calls), or [Should Unit Tests test against the REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321402/should-unit-tests-test-against-the-rest-api).